# JVM Tuning:Class data sharing

Tags: java, performance, jvm-arguments

I have read a good deal about class data sharing [[Ref 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/class-data-sharing.html), [Ref 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-sharedclasses/)]

I am using a JRockit JDK 6. I wanted to know if JRockit JDK 6 supports "-Xshare" and can it coexist with "-XgcPrio:deterministic" ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Did you see this note [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/aboutjrockit.htm)? Nonstandard -X options adhere to the Java compatibility statement (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/compatibility.html).